# Showing Values in an Array on Each Row

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I have vigorously tried solving this problem every way I know how and have come to no avail, any assistance with this problem would be great.

I am trying to create an array of numbers (1 through 50) and show each number on a different row in the View Controller.

I am running into a roadbump where Xcode is suggesting that there should be a return value, however if I put the return value outside of the for loop it won't be recognized (see picture for visual representation).

[image]

Comment: remove the `for i in numbers {` loop and the closing bracket `}` and change `String(i)` to `numbers[indexPath.row]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First of all create an array of integer  like this

```
var numbers = Array(0...50)
```

And then replace your cellForRowAt  method by

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    // since this method is called each time a cell is about to display so for loop is not the correct way set text to a textLabel
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(numbers[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

And make sure your dataSource is connected to your UIViewController, otherwise you would not be able to see data in UITableView.